# ¿Conectar servicio SOAP con REST mediante conector de datos?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, soap, microservices

Estoy aprendiendo a realizar conectores de datos en entorno .NET, sin embargo, los servicios que dispongo internos son todos SOAP, y veo que la gran mayoría de los externos que hay disponibles son REST, mi pregunta es sí es posible realizar un conector de datos que pase datos de un servicio REST a uno SOAP en .NET. También quisiera preguntar por algo de documentación para hacerlo, si la conocéis... Gracias

Comment: Se puede, seguro. Dependiendo de las necesidades de tu negocio, puedes hacer la capa de adaptación "a mano", o si necesitas control y unos flujos de negocio definidos, un proceso BPEL que consuma unos y otros. Más allá de ésto, tu pregunta es muuuuy amplia y, por ello mismo, posiblemente termine cerrada. Lo que comentas al final, en el [chat] posiblemente pueda charlarse

Comment: Muchas gracias!